# Singleton property on springboot

Tags: spring-boot

Can I create one singleton property in spring boot?

When I use this:

```
public class MessengerPlatformCallbackHandler {

    @Scope(value = "singleton")
    private Map<String, Object> conversationID = new HashMap<>();
```

I got the erro: @Scope not applicable to field

tks

Comment: By default bean scope is singleton you don't need to do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create it this way.

```
@Configuration
public class ConversationIDConfig {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "singleton")
    public Map<String, Object> conversationId(){
        private Map<String, Object> conversationID = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

And later you can inject it where ever you want as below.

```
public class MessengerPlatformCallbackHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, Object> conversationID;

}
```

Comment: Just remember, even though `@Scope(value = "singleton")` makes it clear that the bean being defined is a singleton, singleton is the default scope of a spring bean.   In the above code block, only `@Bean` is enough to create a 'singleton' bean :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create it this way.

```
@Configuration
public class ConversationIDConfig {
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> conversationId(){
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

And later you can inject it where ever you want as below.

```
public class MessengerPlatformCallbackHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, Object> conversationId;

}
```